# SQLite database file upload at server in SQL format

Tags: android, sqlite, client-server, android-sqlite

I want to upload local sqlite database file at server but in sql format. Is it possible to directly save it in mysql supported format? The file is uploaded successfully on server but its just a flat file of sqlite db. When i open it in editplus or import it in phpmyadmin, it shows error. But when I manually export the database from sqlite manager in .sql extension, it successfully gets open in readable format in editplus. Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance !

Comment: IMO, it is not much smart to exchange data between databases via SQL commands. Why don't you use two database connections, query source and write target? Programatically, seams much cleaner to me. And faster, as bulk inserts will also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK you are talking about two completely different things.**

**`Its like comparing a DB dump file to a properly exported file like an xml file with schema and data information from Oracle or MySql`**

When you export you get a file with or without ***.sql*** extension and it means a file with set of queries like **DDL** or **DML** `create`,`insert` etc. That may be sequentially run to execute all the commands in it and provide you with the right schema and data present in that file.

Whereas a DB file that is created via app is specific to the device and is an ***.sqlite*** file which is specific to **sqlite browser and that may read it** and not a set of queries only that you may open in edit-plus or a text editor.

**Sqlite DB file that you find on your device is dynamically generated pages to maintain the integrity of the db.**

For more info you must read,

[Format of sqlite database](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

Sorry I don't have code but the idea is,

**--Edit with algo--**

**Assuming you have the create commands for all tables and constraints with you , as they are not going to change most of the time.**

> You may use this function as a Utility to create and maintain the sql
>   command list for you parallel to the db you have.

```
void createExportCommands()
{
...

 - Read all tables one by one using a `Cursor`
 - Based on specific tables/columns create queries 
i.e. String query="insert into "+your_table+" values("+cursor.getString(0),....+");";
 - Write this data into a file called export_data.sql and keep updating it in background

}
```

***Perhaps its not the best approach but it will solve your issue.***

Comment: I know the difference between them. But my requirement is to convert the sqlite database flat file which is created in my application directly in .sql format programmatically. Is it possible??

Comment: Well if there is no other way you would like to solve your problem then I will suggest to write a Utility class with methods and those would read the db and that data could be written to another file and this way you would create a file with sql commands similar to export. This is time consuming for the first time but then this method will help you throughout !!

Comment: Can you share the sample code for the solution you gave me above? I am still in the learning phase of Android!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I successfully uploaded the db file on server :) Now I have one more problem while restoring the database from server in my application. I want to download the same backup database which is on server in sql format. I converted it back in .sqlite format and successfully downloaded the file in my application. But now when I again try to do operations taking that downloaded file, my application crashes down. I checked the error from logcat and it shows error on line db.execSQL(query). Can you help me with some way of solving this error?

Comment: @Anu Paste the error log and edit your question!! Also make sure by pulling the db from sd-card and opening in Sqlite Browser if the db is corrupted or not

Comment: Yes I checked, the file is not corrupted. The problem is in extracting all the data from downloaded file and copying it in original database.

Comment: Make sure you are using the right DB NAME the one you are reading and you have the right permissions to read data.

Comment: I have to fetch the table name with database name. For e.g. if I want to get table "a" from database "abc.sqlite" , I am firing the following query:
String query = "select * from " + DB_NAME + "." + table_name + ";";

I checked what query its taking in Log, and it is taking query as "select * from abc.sqlite.a;" 

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to open the database using `your_context.openOrCreateDatabase(pass db name here ,null,null)` function

Comment: I opened the database using same function, but its still showing error on myContext.openOrCreateDatabase(new_db, 0, null); this line.

Comment: What's the error you should share the complete log-cat . Copy it and paste it while editing your question here.